# Finding n-gram frequencies in a large set of sentences

Tags: javascript, algorithm, substring, string-matching

I have a set of text messages. Lets call them `m1, m2, ....`. The maximum number of message is below `1,000,000`. Each message is below `1024` characters in length, and all are in lowercase. Lets also pick an n-gram `s1`.

I need to find frequency of all possible substring from all of these messages. For example, lets say we have only two messages:

```
m1 = a cat in a cage
m2 = a bird in a cage
```

The frequency of some n-gram in these two messages:

```
'a' = 4
'in a cage' = 2
'a bird' = 1
'a cat' = 1
...
```

Note that, as `in = 2`, `in a = 2`, and `a cage = 2` are subsets of `in a cage = 2` and have same frequency, they should not be listed. Only take the longest one that have the highest frequency; follow this condition: the longest sn-gram should consist of at most 8 words, with a total character count below 30. If a n-gram exceeds this limit, it can be broken into two or more n-grams and listed separately.

I need to find such n-grams for all of these text messages and sort them by their number of occurrences in descending order.

How to I approach this problem? I need a solution in javascript.

> PS: I need help, but do not know to where to ask this. If the question
>   is not for this site, then where should I post it? please guide this
>   newbie here.

Comment: Basically in SO you are expected to seek for help on your not working code. But out of curiosity let me ask.. for what purpose you need to do this task..?

Comment: Hi. I do not have any code at all. I do not even know where to begin. I need to find the mostly used part of sentences from a list of messages. It is for a text analysis program I am working on.

Comment: you probably want to start by searching the web a little: Wikipedia and a number of other resources explain "topological sorting" from conceptual to "here is actual, working code" across the first 20 results I get from Google for the term, and you probably also want to search for how others have implemented by using slightly different terminology: in text searching, you're looking for "n-gram frequency counting", as n-grams are words in text, whereas substrings are letters in a string. That should get you well on your way to finding quite a few hints and implementations.

Comment: the problem may not be related to "topological sorting". I was thinking about it as a possibility. but later I thought it will be bad to post my guess, as I may be horribly wrong. so I changed the title. I have no idea what "n-gram frequency counting" is. thank you for the term. I will look into it.

Comment: One question is "why implement this yourself?" if this isn't a homework exercise. If this is for something real that you're working on, install a full text indexer like Elastic Search and use that to do the work for you? (or, set up your database to build an ngram index and then see if you can get the frequency information it has to track already anyway?)

Comment: I am doing a small project, not something big or fancy. And I am definitely not thinking to do it manually. I just need some way to do it. I will look into "elastic search" to check if it can solve the problem. if you are experienced in it, can you tell me how can I solve this using elastic search?

Comment: You can solve this problem using suffix automata. Look here to find more about it: https://cp-algorithms.com/string/suffix-automaton.html

Comment: Thank you very much. but a working code would help a lot. can anyone give me something that I can plug-n-play? I want to build a simple app, but I am stuck at this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can approach as follows. I will edit to add explanation as soon as i have some time.

```js
var subSentences = (w,...ws) => ws.length ? ws.reduce((r,s) => (r.push(r[r.length-1] + ` ${s}`), r),[w])
                                              .concat(subSentences(...ws))
                                          : [w],
    frequencyMap = sss => sss.reduce((map,ss) => subSentences(...ss.split(/\s+/)).reduce((m,s) => m.set(s, m.get(s) + 1 || 1), map), new Map());

    frequencies  = frequencyMap(["this is a test string",
                                 "this is another one",
                                 "yet another one is here"]);

console.log(...frequencies.entries()); // logging map object seems not possible hence entries
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height : 100% !important
                    }
```

Comment: this snippet almost works. Except it should combine `["this", 2], ["this is", 2]` into one: ` ["this is", 2]`. Nevertheless, thank you for posting it. I could not figure out how to do it by myself.